# Why simple connected Kahler Calabi-Yau threefold is projective?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

A Calabi-Yau manifold $X$ is defined to be a compact Kahler manifold with $c_1(X)=0$. We also assume it is simple connected in the following.

It seems that in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.01273v2.pdf) (see the bottom of the first page and the beginning of the second page), the authors claimed that "simple connected Kahler Calabi-Yau threefold is projective".

I was not able to figure this out, could anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent by the Calabi conjecture to the existence of a Kahler metric on $M$ with vanishing Ricci curvature. Then you can apply formulas relating two different kinds of Laplacians to see that holomorphic $(k,0)$-forms are parallel, and which because the holonomy is $SU(3)$ implies that $b^{2,0}=0$. Now the Kahler cone is open in $H^{1,1}$, and because of the above vanishing Betti number, it's open in $H^2$. $H^2(X;\Bbb Q)$ is dense here, and thus you can find a rational Kahler form. Taking an appropriate multiple, we can choose the Kahler form to be integral, apply the Kodaira embedding theorem, and we're done.

Comment: The argument does not need simply-connected, does it?